# Updating ListView row's without losing SeekBar focus

Tags: android, android-listview, focus, seekbar

I have a `ListView` with a row of items, where each row contains a `SeekBar` and `TextView`. Whenever I move any of the `SeekBar`'s I need to have all the `TextView`'s in the `ListView` updated live, without losing focus on the `SeekBar`.

I have tried to

- call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `ListView`, but the
  `SeekBar` loses focus.
- loop through the `ListView` with the following code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++)
{
TextView tv = (TextView) listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.textView1);
String value = getData();
tv.setText(value);
}
```

However, the code above doesn't give a persistent update to the `ListView`, which is a problem if the user scrolls.

Any suggestions how to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Whenever I move any of the SeekBar's I need to have all the TextView's
>   in the ListView updated live, without losing focus on the SeekBar.

What you want to do is updating the data list of the adapter without calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` and then also update the `TextViews` from the currently visible rows.

```
//...
@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
    // found is a reference to the ListView    
    int firstVisible = found.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    // first update the mData which backs the adapter               
    for (int i = 0; i < mData.size(); i++) {
          // update update update   
    }
    // update the visible rows
    for (int j = 0; j < found.getChildCount(); j++) {
           final View row = found.getChildAt(j);
           // get the position from the mData by offseting j with the firstVisible position
       ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.theIdOfTheTextView)).setText(mData.get(firstVisible + j));
    }
}
//...
```

This should offer you a smooth update.

Comment: You made me realise that I simply forgot to update the data which backs the adapter.